# My c++ program doesn´t print any char, but if I change them to int the code works perfectly

Tags: c++, printing, char

My problem is that when I want to print the data inside my vector, it prints the blanc space where a char is suposed to be. If I change the chars to int it works perfectly. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Editor
{
public:
    int xtam,ytam;
    vector<vector<char> >Tab;
    vector<char> temp;
    Editor(){}  
    void setI(int x, int y)
    {    
        xtam = x;
        ytam = y; 
        for (int i = 0; i<xtam; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j<ytam; j++)
            {
                temp.push_back(0);
            }
            Tab.push_back(temp);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<xtam; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<ytam; j++)
            {
                cout << Tab[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }
    void setL(int r, int s, char A)
    {
        Tab[1][1] = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i<xtam; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<ytam; j++)
            {
                cout << Tab[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    string comando;
    Editor inicio;

    while (comando != "X")
    {
        cin >> comando;
        if (comando == "I")
        {
            cout << "I"<< endl;
            int x, y;
            cin >> x;
            cin >> y;
            inicio.setI(x, y);

        }
        else if (comando == "L")
        {
            cout << "L" << endl;
            int r, s;
            char A;
            cin >> r;
            cin >> s;
            cin >> A;
            inicio.setL(r,s,A);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is a photo of what it´s printing:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybqcg.png)

Comment: `0` is not `'0'`.

Comment: Just to say, you do not use the input parameters you pass to the function void `setL(int r, int s, char A)`

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the `0` value as a char (which is not equal to `'0'`, as @LogicStuff mentioned), which will be interpreted as the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of NULL. You should change this line: `temp.push_back(0);` to this `temp.push_back('0');`. If you want to use the ASCII value of '0' then you should change it to this: `temp.push_back(48);`.